# Remove rows with distinct value in column 2 when grouped with column 1

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this

| col 1 | col 2 |
| --- | --- |
| s | x |
| s | c |
| a | b |
| a | b |
| y | z |
| y | h |
| y | h |
| j | k |

i want it to return

| col 1 | col 2 |
| --- | --- |
| s | x |
| s | c |
| y | z |
| y | h |
| y | h |

So essentially if there is only a 1 to 1 relationship between per each distinct value in column 1, remove those rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col1 = t.col1 and t2.col2 <> t.col2);
```

If you are concerned about performance, then an index on `(col1, col2)` should make this as fast or faster than any other methods.

Comment: does this work if there's like 10 or so columns of other random stuff?

Comment: @hospital_questions . . . Yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the analytical function `count` as follows

```
Select * from
(Select t.*,
       Count(distinct col2) over (partition by col1) as c
  From your_table t) t
 Where c > 1
```

Comment: does this work if there's like 10 or so columns of other random stuff?